# pandas grouper issue with key that is an index

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe with the following form:

```
                Response
Time    
2018-01-14 00:00:00 201
2018-01-14 00:00:00 400
2018-01-14 00:00:00 200
2018-01-14 00:00:00 400
2018-01-14 00:00:00 200
```

Time is the index column.

I wanted to get graphs for the responses grouped over time (15 min intervals) so I wrote the following:

```
for ind, itm in enumerate(df_final['Response'].unique()):
    ax=df_final[df_final['Response'] == itm].groupby(pd.Grouper(key='Time',freq='15Min')).count().plot(kind='bar', figsize=(15,10), title="Response Codes")
    ax.legend(["Response: {}".format(itm)])
```

This worked with the depreciated TimeGrouper where the second line in the above code was:

```
ax=df_final[df_final['Response'] == item].groupby(pd.TimeGrouper(freq='15Min')).count().plot(kind='bar', figsize=(15,10), title="Response Codes")
```

but when I run the Grouper code I get the error:

```
KeyError: 'The grouper name Time is not found'
```

I also changed the key to be df_final.index.name but that also resulted in KeyError: 'The grouper name Time is not found'

The index was of type index but I changed it to DatetimeIndex:

```
type(df_final.index)

pandas.core.indexes.datetimes.DatetimeIndex
```

After I changed the index type and ran :

```
ax=df_final[df_final['Response'] == itm].groupby(pd.Grouper(key=df_final.index, freq='15Min')).count().plot(kind='bar', figsize=(15,10), title="Response Codes")
```

I got:

```
TypeError: unhashable type: 'DatetimeIndex'
```

I'm obviously missing something. What am I doing wrong here?

Just to show what the index is df_final.index gave the result:

```
DatetimeIndex(['2018-01-14 00:00:00', '2018-01-14 00:00:00',
           '2018-01-14 00:00:00', '2018-01-14 00:00:00',
           '2018-01-14 00:00:00', '2018-01-14 00:00:00',
           '2018-01-14 00:00:00', '2018-01-14 00:00:00',
           '2018-01-14 00:00:00', '2018-01-14 00:00:00',
           ...
           '2018-01-15 00:00:00', '2018-01-15 00:00:00',
           '2018-01-15 00:00:00', '2018-01-15 00:00:00',
           '2018-01-15 00:00:00', '2018-01-15 00:00:00',
           '2018-01-15 00:00:00', '2018-01-15 00:00:00',
           '2018-01-15 00:00:00', '2018-01-15 00:00:00'],
          dtype='datetime64[ns]', name='Time', length=48960011, freq=None)
```

after some investigation with the aid of jezrael it looks like the issue is in the plot method. I broke up the code into:

```
for ind, itm in enumerate(df_final['Response'].unique()):
    ax=df_final[df_final['Response'] == itm].groupby(pd.Grouper(level='Time', freq='15Min')).count()
    ax.plot(kind='bar', figsize=(15,10), title="Response Codes")
```

and the error occurs in the plot line is:

```
~/anaconda2/envs/py3env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/plotting/_core.py in __init__(self, data, kind, by, subplots, sharex, sharey, use_index, figsize, grid, legend, rot, ax, fig, title, xlim, ylim, xticks, yticks, sort_columns, fontsize, secondary_y, colormap, table, layout, **kwds)
     98                  table=False, layout=None, **kwds):
     99 
--> 100         _converter._WARN = False
    101         self.data = data
    102         self.by = by

NameError: name '_converter' is not defined
```

I dont know if I did something wrong or if there is an error in matplotlib but this is the position I find myself stuck on. The previous line ax shows counts and times as expected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that it was the matplotlib version that was the issue. When I went back to version 2.0.2 I had no issues. Just uninstall matplotlib version 2.1.1 using:

```
! pip uninstall -y matplotlib && pip install matplotlib==2.0.2
```

and import matplotlib again and the code all works

Answer (score 10):

I think you need:

```
pd.Grouper(level='Time',freq='15Min')
```

I believe you can add column `Response` to `groupby`, reshape by `unstack` and plot:

```
a = df_final.groupby([pd.Grouper(level='Time',freq='15Min'), 'Response'])['Response'].count()
a.unstack().plot(kind='bar', figsize=(15,10), title="Response Codes")
```

Comment: that gives the error: NameError: name '_converter' is not defined

Comment: OK, what about another solution? `pd.Grouper(level='Time',freq='15Min')` ?

Comment: NameError: name '_converter' is not defined

Comment: What is your pandas version?

Comment: I assume the latest. I did a pip install pandas just this morning. How do you find ou the version that was installed?

Comment: pandas version is 0.22.0

Comment: It is weird :( For me it working nice, if omit `level='Time'` too.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163254/discussion-between-amadain-and-jezrael).

Comment: NameError: name '_converter' is not defined

Comment: also resample also gives the error NameError: name '_converter' is not defined

Comment: OK, what is desired output? multiple plots in one graph? Or for each loop separately graph?

Comment: for this each loop separately a graph but I could take the graphing out of the loop and have them all in one

Comment: ax.unstack().plot( gave the error in ----> 6     ax.unstack().plot(kind='bar', figsize=(15,10), title="Response Codes") that was, again,NameError: name '_converter' is not defined

Comment: hmmm, maybe need reinstall matplotlib I guess.

Comment: I reinstalled and got the same issue

Comment: I have idea - do you use `anaconda` ? and spyder? I test it there and no problem.

Comment: yea I'll check that. Could it be that there are almost 49 million entries in the dataframe?

Comment: Yes, it is possible, if very large data and not really huge RAM get weird errors sometimes ;)

Comment: I'll retry tomorrow. Gotta head now. Thx for your help

Comment: will you explain what pd.grouper is doing?